# Auto-renewable subscription how long 1 month/ 3 months and 1 year

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, app-store-connect, subscription, auto-renewable

Is there any official apple documentation that have mentioned the number of dates for each auto-renewal subscription plans that they have defined. I checked around their documentations and couldn't find any reliable documentation.

Please help if anyone has an idea about the count of dates of the auto-renewal subscription plans

thanks

Answer (score 0):

They didn't mention the days for any time period of subscription, If you want after purchasing the subscription by the user, you will get the expiry date for that purchase. Then you have to calculate the days between **purchase date** and **expiry date**.

If you want to show the user before purchasing the subscription details, you have to show the user, for example, $0.99/(Monthly or 1 Month), $1.99/(3 Month or Quarterly), $2.99/(Half yearly or 6 months),$4.99(Yearly or 1 year), $0.49/(1 Week or 7 days).

Comment: Yeh. That's what I am keeping as the last option. but waiting till my auto renewable  subscription plans getting approved. :) Also we had put an email to apple support by asking the same. I will update if they reply back.

Comment: @chinthakad Have you got any replay from apple support?